# SQL Server Compact Edition- byte array truncation to a length of 8000 exception

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I am programming for a Windows Mobile 6.5 device.

I am using SQL Server Compact Edition, and am trying to write a byte stream to the database.
The column type is `image` (which I understand can handle more than 8000 bytes), however I am getting the exception:

> InvalidOperationException
>   @signature : Byte array truncation to a length of 8000.

Any idea why this is happening?

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO E_CONS_SIGNATURE (CONS_NO, SIGNATURE, SIGNATURE_FORMAT, SIGNATURE_DATE)"
            + " VALUES(@consNo, @signature, @format, @date)";

SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@consNo", txtConsignment.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@signature", ms.ToArray());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@format", "BMP");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", new DateTime());

bool success = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
```

Storing on the file system is not an option at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

On the error itself there is a problem on this line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@signature", ms.ToArray());
```

You need to convert your image to MemoryStream object.

Check the below site to help you.

[Save images to SQL CE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/0fb5fd05-3eb5-4568-9e2a-fd9ba5ed5a3e/)

[Store an image in a SQL Server CE database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638259/store-an-image-in-a-sql-server-ce-database)

Regards