# How I can make a variable to varbinary(max) when length limit is 8000 in SQL Server compact

Tags: sql

Yeah, stupid question but I cant make it to max even it should be possible. It just allows me to put only 8000 to varbinary and not max. I tried this in edit table schema when i right clicked the table in server explorer.

Comment: [SQL Server CE does not support varbinary(max), but you can use the "old" image type.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638259/store-an-image-in-a-sql-server-ce-database)

Comment: Above comment should be turned into the answer and accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant! SQL server CE doesn't support VARBINARY(MAX) the equivilant would be image but i believe they are phasing that out